# List Onload event

Tags: 2010, development, javascript, client-object-model, event-handlers

**What I want to do:**
I have a custom list that contains a lot of items. When an user loads the list, all items of his view should be checked. If there is a special value in the listitem a notifiaction should be added.

**What I've tried:**
I didn't find a way to trigger the onload event. I've searched in the custom `ListEventReceiver` and in the `Javascript ClientModel`.

Does any one have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you need to select ALL items in the whole list? Or only on the current page?

Comment: @RubenHerman only the Items of the current page!

Comment: Ok, than you can still use the anwser I described below. To check all items faster, you can also include jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a combination of js and the sharepoint client object model (client object model is to check te value of a listitem).

Use this function to start your code after the sharepoint js is loaded:

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myInitMethod, "sp.js");
```

Comment: where do I implement this code?

Comment: you have some possibilities... you can add it in a js file, add a scriptblock to your (master)page, add a content editor webpart and edit the html

Comment: here are some examples: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.be/2012/05/adding-javascript-and-css-to-sharepoint.html